# How to configure a secondary 21:9 screen for Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I use a 21:9 screen both as the primary screen of my PC (eOS Freya) and a secondary one of my Notebook (Ubuntu 16.04). While the display of my PC is rendered perfectly in the desired 2560x1080p, my Notebook only renders the Picture in 1920x1080p, which is quite unpleasant as the picture is stretched.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What GPU are you running? Also, please post the results of `xrandr`.

Comment: Its a GTX960M and xrandr only Lists 1920*1080 downwards and different Frequencies

Comment: We unfortunately do not support ElementaryOS here. Didn't point this out the first time, sorry. Try the Unix and Linux StackExchange.

Comment: Unfortunately, its a Ubuntu Problem, so I wont try the eOS or Unix Stack-Exchange. You would know that if you had read my original Post.

Answer (score 0):

the list of resolutions you see are merely some defaults the drivers deem appropriate for you, you can tweak the defaults by xorg.conf - this is however for advanced users and I did not do it for ages. Google for things like xconfig, xprofile, xsessionrc and so on. This guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution will also come handy. And do not forget to post results here as this ancient magic is worth unearthing :-)

Answer (score -1):

You find the basic configuration for the displays under *Config>Displays*. Click there on the screen you want to config and in the bottom right corner you can choose beetween the available resolutions. If the resolution you want is on in the list, maybe you need to change drivers for the graphic card or is not supported.

Comment: I already tried but its Not listet. Both the driver and the Card support the Resolution